# How to change the default fonts in Windows 10

Tags: fonts, windows-10

I have read the entries for other OS versions.

- Changing the MS Shell Dlg (2) entries in FontSubstitues registry key
  doesn't seem to work (in Windows 10), or it works in two minor
  places.
- I don't have access to a Windows 95/98/etc. machine, the
  "earliest" I have is Windows 8.1, so I can't use the Plus directory
  trick either (directory doesn't exist).
- For the WindowMetrics registry entry, I seem to have all the *Font keys to be set to the font I want, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick (on Windows 10).
- For Windows 8/8.1, there was a program called `Windows 8 Font Changer`, which worked like a charm, but doesn't seem to on Windows 10 (though it was probably that program run that changed the fonts in the WindowMetrics).

Thanks.

Update: One more method that came out that is perhaps still not the solution: Winaero Tweaker (winaero.com), as it has some issues, the biggest two of which seem to be:

- If you have changed the size of text etc. from: "Settings –> Display –> Advanced display settings –> Advanced sizing of text and other items –> set a custom scaling level (not recommended)", the changes do not stick upon a logoff-login or restart. You need to have changed it, if at all, only through "Settings –> Display –> Change the size of text, etc." (which goes up to only a certain percentage, depending on the maximum resolution of your device – 125% on a tablet of mine, which I was able to set to 175% or even 200% with the other, older method that is now apparently listed as not recommended).
- Even though it lists a number of items to change the font and size of, not everything gets changed. A typical example of this is the right click menu on the desktop, which still shows the View, Sort By, etc. items in the default font, however much it has a clear 'Change menu font' item.

Answer (score 18):

You can change Windows 10 icon fonts with the following procedure:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Type `regedit.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Go to the following path:

   ```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
   ```

   You can find `Segoe UI = Tahoma` or similar on the right. Before changing the font value, note the default value somewhere.
4. Find and double-click on `Segoe UI` to change its value. (in my case, it's `Tahoma`.)
5. Enter the font name in `Segoe UI`'s value data and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Restart to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks, Naveed. For some reason, I haven't received notification of the response, even though I have ' Email me my unread inbox messages' set to Daily 9 (I might not have enough reputation points to get notifications!) Your method will probably work for the icon fonts, even though I have changed that font to Georgia through some other method (that I'll try to post below as the potential answer), I can find neither Segue UI nor Georgia in that registry entry. In addition to the Icons, I also need the ones for Caption, Menu, Message, and Status.  Thanks again.

Comment: Segoe. The default font is Segoe.

Comment: @ElliottWinslow you may be right...