# Default font in windows server 2012 r2 standard

Tags: fonts, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed some new fonts on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and after first restart I found that windows fonts changed like yellow box in the picture :

[image]

I tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/950893/how-to-change-the-default-fonts-in-windows-10) solution,but no luck.

Comment: The value `Segoe UI` need not be there. You may use the fix (or steps) here: [How to Reset Default System Font Settings (to Segoe UI) in Windows?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-font-default-settings-segoe-ui-windows/)

Comment: @w32sh Thank you so much,it works.If you put the solution as a full answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `Segoe UI` need not be there under `FontSubstitutes`. This REG file resets the main system font settings to defaults:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"=-
```

Src: [How to Reset Default System Font Settings (to Segoe UI) in Windows?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-font-default-settings-segoe-ui-windows/)