# Scrambled characters in the Irfanview zoom dropdown menu

Tags: irfanview

I am using Irfanview 4.50 (32 bit) on Windows 10 version 1709.

The dropdown menu of the zoom options contains scrambled characters. These should be numerical percentages (from 10% to 500%) but are instead displayed like this: 
[image: You're not allowed to embed images]

Both the 32 bit and 64 bit of Irfanview have this problem on my computer. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling many times and this problem persists.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be due to language, whether that selected for the installation of IrfanView, in the default Windows language settings, or of available fonts.

First check that the system font is the default, Segoe UI. This can be changed, but [only through Registry hacks](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-default-system-font-windows-10), AFAIK. [Another Registry setting controls font *substitution*](https://superuser.com/questions/950893/how-to-change-the-default-fonts-in-windows-10), which could also be the source of the problem, if Segoe UI is the Windows font, but another can be  substituted. My font substitution settings are blow as an example.

[image: My font substitution settings]

If that doesn't fix the issue, then check your Windows language settings, including number representation.

[image: Windows language settings]