# Changing default fonts in Windows 10 - without restarting

Tags: windows, fonts

I'm running a program that relies on the Windows default system font to render its text.

Unfortunately I have not been able to get the program to use a different font. What I was able to do is change the default system font using the method described here:
[How to change the default fonts in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/950893/how-to-change-the-default-fonts-in-windows-10)

However, as this is a registry change that requires a restart I'm looking for something more dynamic and possibly less intrusive.
The optimum would be a way to launch the program while somehow overriding the system font setting just for the specific process. A solution that's not as good would be finding a way to change the system setting without having to restart Windows.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: At this time there is no way to change the default system font without restarting your machine at least once.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound.