# How to change font to default Windows 10 font

Tags: fonts

1 year ago I changed my font to SF Pro, and I deleted that font by accident. Now I don't know which font I'm using.

how can I know what font I'm using?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ1tB.jpg

I tried to reset font to default but it says this https://i.stack.imgur.com/eapkF.jpg

I want Segoe UI font

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default fonts in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/950893/how-to-change-the-default-fonts-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-default-system-font-windows-10#restore_change_default_font_windows10) it worked for me. (them talking about a system restore point and backup is a really good idea! Better Backup than sorry!)

**How to restore default system font on Windows 10 - Undo settings with Registry**

To restore the default font settings on Windows 10, use these steps:

Open Start.
Search for Notepad and click the top result to open the text editor.

Copy and paste the following Registry code onto the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black (TrueType)"="seguibl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)"="seguibli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)"="seguiemj.ttf"
"Segoe UI Historic (TrueType)"="seguihis.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)"="seguili.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)"="seguisbi.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)"="segoeuisl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)"="seguisli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"
"Segoe MDL2 Assets (TrueType)"="segmdl2.ttf"
"Segoe Print (TrueType)"="segoepr.ttf"
"Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)"="segoeprb.ttf"
"Segoe Script (TrueType)"="segoesc.ttf"
"Segoe Script Bold (TrueType)"="segoescb.ttf"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Segoe UI"=-
```

Click the *File* menu.

Select the *Save as* option.

Use the *"Save as type"* drop-down menu and select the *All Files* option.

Confirm a descriptive name for the file, such as "restore-default-font," and use the ".reg" as the extension – for example, restore-default-font.reg.

Click the *Save* button.

Right-click the newly created ".reg" file and select the *Merge* option.

Click the *Yes* button.

Click the *OK* button.

**Now you should have back the default system font!**

To change the font to something else use the same .reg template as before looking like this: (You should put in the font name on the line called *"Segoe UI"="NEW-FONT-NAME"*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Segoe UI"="NEW-FONT-NAME"
```

***for further explanation checkout the link at the top!***