# How to change the English font of the Windows 11 Start menu

Tags: windows, fonts

I am using the Chinese version of Windows 11, and the default font of the system is Microsoft Yahei.

I disguised [LXGW WenKai](https://github.com/lxgw/LxgwWenKai) as Microsoft YaHei, and then replaced the corresponding fonts in the "C:\Windows\Fonts" directory with the disguised "msyh.ttc", "msyhl.ttc", and "msyhbd.ttc" fonts.

I can change most of the fonts displayed by the system, but the English in the Windows start menu is still in Microsoft YaHei.

[This is a screenshot of the Windows Start menu, where it is obvious that the Chinese and English fonts are inconsistent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrRoD.png)

[This image shows the appearance of LXGW WenKai font displaying Chinese and English.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8euM.png)

What should I do to make the English text in the Windows start menu use the LXGW WenKai font?

**I have read [How to change the default fonts in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/950893/how-to-change-the-default-fonts-in-windows-10), but it doesn't work for me.**

Comment: Do you wish to change the font only in the Start menu or in the entire Windows ([link](https://www.lifewire.com/change-font-windows-11-6827640)).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @harrymc I want to change the font of the entire Windows, but the problem I am currently facing is that the font of the start menu has not changed. The link you provided also mentions this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Start menu is unfortunately a UWP application.

[Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform)
is a computing platform created by Microsoft for developing
universal apps. UWP wasn't successful among the developers and is
basically seen as a failure, but parts of Windows have been rewritten
in it, including the Start menu.

UWP apps do not obey all the classical rules, so the methods you used
do not apply.

In the post
[Help with start menu font please](https://www.tenforums.com/customization/85201-help-start-menu-font-please.html),
user Edwin has remarked:

> To change fonts in the UWP UI, you would need to change a lot of things in a lot of Windows System Apps folders; True Type Fonts, Style Sheets, rewrite Appx manifests, etc.!
> I looked into it, too much work and risk! Wasn't worth it!
>
> Here's one example:

[image]

Third-party alternatives to Microsoft's Start menu are much more
customizable.

Here are some of them:

- [Open-Shell-Menu](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/) (free).
  Emulates the Windows 7 menu.
- [Stardock Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/)
  (€6.99 with trial).
  The most complete : Emulates Windows 7, 10 and 11.

Comment: According to the information you provided, I checked the contents of the file "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppxManifest.xml". Unfortunately, there is no font-related configuration in it. I have another idea: I have already replaced the font "Microsoft YaHei" to display custom fonts in the Chinese part of the Windows Start menu, so all we need to do is find the font used for English and replace it to complete the entire change. The problem is that I am not sure what this English font is.

Comment: I usually don't counsel replacing Windows files, but in addition I couldn't guess which font is used in Chinese Windows.